# Sort and retrieve data with drop down menus in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have two drop down menus on my webpage. One is a course list and the other is a student list. What I want to do is, when a selection is made in the course menu it will update the student menu to only list students in that course.

All the course and student data is saved in a MySQL database. The SQL statements to retrieve the results I want are not a problem. I have those figured out. The problem is that I don't know how to get one drop down menu to update the other without the use of a submit button. Is there a way to have the course menu call a php function when it changes, and that will update the student menu?

I've looked through several similar questions, but a lot of them end up resetting the first menu when the second is updated. I need to print both the selected course and student on the page at the end.

Is this something that can be done with PHP, or would Javascript be more preferable? If someone could point em in the right direction, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: One way to do this would be to use AJAX. Please look at http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: @Jian Please do not link to w3schools. It is [full of inaccurate information](http://w3fools.com/) and promotes hazardously bad programming practices. Many of the common questions here are the direct result of the sorts of bad advice that site dishes out.

Comment: @tadman Everyone says that, but I have yet to see an example of "hazardously bad programming practices", or even "inaccurate information".

Comment: It is merely an example and it gives a possible solution for his question. I could have merely said use AJAX, but you are indeed right on that.

Comment: @cypher That example is hazardously bad: It promotes the idea of using `intval` to escape SQL values, which, given the example uses `mysqli`, is completely wrong. It should be using placeholders and `bind_param`. That alone is enough to red-flag it. Using string concatenation or interpolation to compose queries is very error-prone, and one tiny mistake could utterly ruin your application when someone cracks it wide open from there.

Comment: @tadman I don't see it that way at all.  It's not promoting anything and I don't see anything that is "wrong".  It's giving a simple example on what AJAX is and how it works.  Bogging down the example in escaping user-input and going into details on which data-access library to use for an **AJAX** example is not necessary and only makes understanding **AJAX** more difficult.  Besides, anyone who calls themselves a *programmer* won't be copying and pasting code they don't understand, and if they do... they deserve to get bit.  That's not the fault of the website.

Comment: @Cypher Don't fight me on this. Using placeholders is **the** safest way to reliably escape data. It makes mistakes **obvious**. Adding the correct escaping takes two more lines, it doesn't bog down anything. You know what bogs things down? People asking why apostrophes don't work in some fields because they don't know any better...or why they're out of a job because the site they sold to a client got hacked. SQL escaping is extremely serious business. Do not think it is above people. It is not hard, and it is is **mandatory**.

Comment: @tadman I'm not convinced. You're examples are contrived and exaggerated. The example on that page is not about preventing SQL Injection, it's about **AJAX**. Yes, I agree that's not production-ready code by any stretch, but *neither is your answer to this question*.  That does not mean that either are insufficient examples of a concept to learn from.

Comment: @Cypher Some people don't know better, but they **need** to know. This is not optional when there's tools out there that can [ruin your site](http://sqlmap.org/) automatically in a matter of seconds. I've been spending more than a year, with the help of many others, to be vigilant about warning people about security problems and offering solutions. Slowly things are getting better. Now people are using PDO or `mysqli` instead of `mysql_query`. Posting links to code with known issues, or posting answers full of holes, is a problem. Remember: SQL escaping is **always** important. No exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have the course menu call a php function when it changes, and that will update the student menu?

Yes.  The buzz-word for this is AJAX.

You will end up using both JavaScript and PHP to do this.  The actual implementation is quite involved, so I will list the basic steps for you.

1. (JavaScript) Bind the `change` event for the course drop down menu.
2. (JavaScript) When that event is fired, capture the selected course and fire an XMLHttpRequest off to your server along with the selected course.
3. (PHP) Capture the selected course, and run the SQL statement to fetch your students.
4. (PHP) Convert the student list to a text format (JSON, XML, delimited-text, etc.) to send back to the browser (using `echo`, `print`, etc).
5. (JavaScript) Populate the student drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to this is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to add a hook to your drop-down selector and trigger an AJAX load on another section of the page, populating that with data retrieved either as an HTML fragment (easy) or JSON data that's turned into one (harder).

A really quick and dirty version is to grab a portion of a page and re-populate the current document with it using `$.load()`:

```
$('#select1').on('change', function() {
  $('#select2').load('select.php #select2', 'select1=' + $(this).val())
})
```

That's the rough idea: When your first selection box changes, load the `select.php` page, or whatever you're using, and add on the parameter `select=N` where `N` is the selected value. It then rips out the `#select2` section and replaces it.

Comment: jQuery does make this pretty easy on the client-side.

Comment: Thank you. Took a little digging for my particular case, but this helped me get it working. Thanks a lot!